# How to put Global Variables in a Globals.js module and access them in other modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables

I feel silly but I can't find a good example of how to do this.  I've seen some that come close and maybe they are right on target but I can't figure it out.

1. How do I create a module that contains all my global variables?
2. How do I export or import or whatever I need to do to use those global variables in another js module?

I'm creating a small application that contains about 6 variables that must have a global scope to my application.  Can someone please show me an example?

Global variables:

```
var scene = viewer.scene;
var ellipsoid = scene.globe.ellipsoid;
var entity;
var newPolygon;
var newOutline;
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
var extensions = gl.getSupportedExtensions();
```

I have the above in a file called globals.js

```
    <script src="Source/globals.js"></script>
    <script src="Source/index.js"></script>
    <script src="Source/positionHandler.js"></script>
    <script src="Source/polyCreate.js"></script>
    <script src="Source/polyUpdate.js"></script>
```

It is listed in the html file.  All appears to work just fine but there is a browser level variable that thinks it's false.  So now I want to be sure global variables are accessible as expected.

```
Globals = {
  scene:       require('scene'),
  ellipsoid:   require('ellipsoid'),
  canvas:      require('canvas')
};
module.exports = Common;
```

or

```
Globals = {
  scene:       require('viewer.scene'),
  ellipsoid:   require('scene.globe.ellipsoid'),
  canvas:      require('document.getElementById("canvas")')
};
module.exports = Common;
```

or

```
Globals = {
    scene      : viewer.scene,
    ellipsoid  : scene.globe.ellipsoid,
    canvas     : document.getElementById("canvas"),
    gl         : canvas.getContext("webgl"),
    extensions : gl.getSupportedExtensions()
};
module.exports = Common;
```

I don't get the **require** and how to set it up.

Comment: What do you mean by "module" exactly?

Comment: Globals.js - a JavaScript file.  Other JavaScript files can see the global variables.

Comment: Load both scripts in your HTML, that's all. But I'd recommend you use Commonjs modules.

Comment: In the context of browser, anything which is defined outside of the context of the function will be treated as global for that function..So _If your variable are declared as globally, you can access them_

Comment: @elclanrs - I think Commonjs modules is what I want but I don't really understand the require part.  Let me add to my example for you.

Comment: Just adding those to a javascript file, i.e. globals.js and including that script before anything else should work fine, provided loading is sequential. It could generally be a good idea to bundle them to a single object so that you know what they are, like var globals = {a:1,b:2}. As the other ladies and gentlemen are suggesting, this is a very crude approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the browser any variable declared outside of a function scope will be a global var (set on the window object). Make sure that your '< script >' tags are in the correct order (declare your globals before you try to access them).

Comment: OK.  I'm not completely crazy.  I am doing that and it appears to work but there is a problem with a browser level variable not working.

Comment: For one thing you are declaring variables and then requiring them as strings, that could be messing you up. What environment are you in? Are you in the browser using webpack?

Comment: I'm in NodeJS.  All the examples I've seen so far are for 'baked in' objects.  I'm trying to figure out how to use require for Cesium map objects.  Definitely the 'require' is confusing me.

Comment: When you require a module it runs that module and gives you back whatever you assign to module.exports in that module. It only runs the module once.

Comment: OH!  So the string in the parenthesis is the name of the module to be required!  Can one set variables in there as well?

Answer (score 1):

This is kinda complex in JavaScript land, and depends on what context you are speaking about. I assume you are talking about code that runs in the browser (vs node), If this is the case, the simplest way would be to use a name spacing object. and imply import it before other code that replies on it.

for example, you could make the file `globals.js` which contains :

```
MyAppGlobals = { property1: "some-value", anotherProperty2: "other-value" };
```

In the html just make sure that `<script src="path/to/globals.js"></script>` is added before any code that depends on the globals.

if you want a more structured approach, check out projects like [webpack](https://webpack.github.io). They are great, but a little complex to set up.

Basically webpack or browserify let you write proper import and export statements (the way you can in node.js) and then preforms a dependency analysis and "compiles" all the needed code into a bundle file which you would then include in your html. (sort of a rough description but I hope it helps)

Comment: webpack is great!  There is even a discussion about commonjs modules but I'm still confused about the require.